# emacs, twoside option doesn't go in documentclass, why?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, emacs, org-mode

I'm typing up some notes in Org-mode (emacs). When I try to export the *.org file  as *.tex file and then get a pdf, I see the **EVEN** page numbers don't appear on the outside of the page as I want them to. I thought may be it was because I had forgotten to include the `\documentclass` option `twoside`. I still can't get the correct page numbering (see picture below). I'm using `fancyhdr` package, and `\fancyhf[...]{...}`command. Can someone please help me figure out the problem?

**PREAMBLE of org file**

```
#+STARTUP: nolatexpreview
#+OPTIONS: toc:t
#+LATEX_CLASS: article
#+LATEX_CLASSOPTIONS: [10pt, twoside, a4paper]
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{esdiff}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{siunitx}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{fancyhdr}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \pagestyle{fancy} % choose page-style
#+LATEX_HEADER: \fancyhf{}  % erase and clean up
#+LATEX_HEADER: \fancyhf[HLE,HRO]{\thepage} % H or F=Header or Footer, LCR=Left, Centre, Right
```

**PREAMBLE of tex file**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\tolerance=1000
\usepackage{esdiff}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy} % choose page-style
\fancyhf{}  % erase and clean up
\fancyhf[HLE,HRO]{\thepage} % H or F=Header or Footer, LCR=Left, Centre, Right
\author{WW}
\date{}
\title{URM}
\hypersetup{
  pdfkeywords={},
  pdfsubject={},
  pdfcreator={Emacs 24.4.1 (Org mode 8.2.10)}}
```

**SCREENSHOT**

I'd like the even page number to be on the outside of the page. The inside is the long edge along which the page rotates. See the red arrow's indication.
[image: page numbering not correct]

Comment: I'm noticing now that the *.tex file isn't taking the documentclass options I'm telling him to take...May be some emacs/org-mode experts can help me out here?

Answer (score 3):

A quick reference to the [Org-handbook online](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/examples/article-class.html) made me realize a typing mistake.

**WRONG:**
 `#+LATEX_CLASSOPTIONS: [10pt,twoside,a4paper]`

**CORRECT:**
 `#+LATEX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [10pt,twoside,a4paper]`

What a difference an underscore sign makes!

Comment: Did this solve your problem entirely?

Comment: Remember it as a good example how stupid software still is in the year 2016.